# Reorganizing Dataframe by Date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a pivot table that shows customer calls by month. It looks like this

```
CompanyName 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
Customer 1  17  30  29  39  15  27  15  10  36  21  18  15
Customer 2  4   11  13  22  34  27  32  17  29  31  17  14
Customer 3  10  7   23  21  7   15  25  0   21  9   12  17
Customer 4  6   10  11  8   3   4   3   8   11  11  18  14
Customer 5  13  7   6   12  6   8   2   10  11  7   10  11
```

I make a date list so that I can display them nicely on a graph.

```
date_list[::-1]
Out[63]: 
['Jul 2015',
 'Jun 2015',
 'May 2015',
 'Apr 2015',
 'Mar 2015',
 'Feb 2015',
 'Jan 2015',
 'Dec 2014',
 'Nov 2014',
 'Oct 2014',
 'Sep 2014',
 'Aug 2014']
```

I would like to reorder the pivot table so that it matches the date_list like so:

```
CompanyName 7   8   9   10  11  12  1   2   3   4   5   6
Customer 1  15  10  36  21  18  15  17  30  29  39  15  27
Customer 2  32  17  29  31  17  14  4   11  13  22  34  27
Customer 3  25  0   21  9   12  17  10  7   23  21  7   15
Customer 4  3   8   11  11  18  14  6   10  11  8   3   4
Customer 5  2   10  11  7   10  11  13  7   6   12  6   8
```

I was looking at how to reorder columns but since this will be dynamically changing by month I got a bit baffled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your pivot table is named `pt`.

```
# Months are off by one because of Python's zero based indexing.
months = {'Jan': 0,
          'Feb': 1,
          'Mar': 2,
          'Apr': 3,
          'May': 4,
          'Jun': 5,
          'Jul': 6,
          'Aug': 7,
          'Sep': 8,
          'Oct': 9,
          'Nov': 10,
          'Dec': 11}

# Get the index value of the first month from your list.
month = months[date_list[0][:3]]

# Now concatenate the results and create you column names.
pt_new = pd.concat([pt.iloc[:, month:], pt.iloc[:, :month]], axis=1)
pt_new.columns = date_list

>>> pt_new
            Aug 2014  Sep 2014  Oct 2014  Nov 2014  Dec 2014  Jan 2015   
Customer 1        10        36        21        18        15        17   
Customer 2        17        29        31        17        14         4   
Customer 3         0        21         9        12        17        10   
Customer 4         8        11        11        18        14         6   
Customer 5        10        11         7        10        11        13   

            Feb 2015  Mar 2015  Apr 2015  May 2015  Jun 2015  Jul 2015  
Customer 1        30        29        39        15        27        15  
Customer 2        11        13        22        34        27        32  
Customer 3         7        23        21         7        15        25  
Customer 4        10        11         8         3         4         3  
Customer 5         7         6        12         6         8         2
```

Comment: Same problem with this answer, once you get the month using month = months[date_list[0][:3]], it is stagnant. I want it to change on a monthly basis depending on what month it is.

Comment: The line `month = months[date_list[0][:3]]` uses the dictionary to get the index value of the first month in your list of dates.  If the list changes, your index value will change, and hence your table columns will shift.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `df` is your pivot table.

```
df

              1   2   3   4   5 ...   8   9  10  11  12
CompanyName                     ...                    
Customer1    17  30  29  39  15 ...  10  36  21  18  15
Customer2     4  11  13  22  34 ...  17  29  31  17  14
Customer3    10   7  23  21   7 ...   0  21   9  12  17
Customer4     6  10  11   8   3 ...   8  11  11  18  14
Customer5    13   7   6  12   6 ...  10  11   7  10  11
```

You can use `pd.concat` to do the trick.

```
pd.concat([df.iloc[:,6:], df.iloc[:,:6]], axis=1)

              7   8   9  10  11 ...   2   3   4   5   6
CompanyName                     ...                    
Customer1    15  10  36  21  18 ...  30  29  39  15  27
Customer2    32  17  29  31  17 ...  11  13  22  34  27
Customer3    25   0  21   9  12 ...   7  23  21   7  15
Customer4     3   8  11  11  18 ...  10  11   8   3   4
Customer5     2  10  11   7  10 ...   7   6  12   6   8

[5 rows x 12 columns]
```

Comment: I like this since it's a one-liner, but it won't update once we move into August, then it will have to be pd.concat([df.iloc[:,7:], df.iloc[:,:7]], axis=1)